# What's the top level pattern of Cocos2d

Tags: design-patterns, cocos2d-iphone

can anyone tell me the name of the top level pattern of cocos2d. I mean the idea is to not split the information in model, view and controller, although this can also be done. (Still I think this is kind of work around, and seems to not meet with the idea of the framework). So why is the concept of MVC not used in cocos2d and what is the pattern called instead that is used?

Comment: Not everyone uses MVC. :) You'd have a better chance of getting this answered on the cocos2d forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/cocos-discuss

Comment: Actually the google group has been dead for years. Use the forum: www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top down, it looks something like this:

> Scenes->Layers->Nodes

As it's game-driven it's less MVC, and more loop based. So you are free to organize your code however you'd like. Thats one of the great things about cocos, is that it's designed around a lot of paradigms.

If you want to use a block instead of a delegate, *you can*. 
If you want to have an event based game, instead of a loop based one, *you can*.
If you want a 3D element inside your 2D game, *you can*.
If you want to put a UIKit element inside your game, *you can*.

That should be the motto of cocos2D: *you can*.